# Comparar tres campos de una tabla si hay coincidencia no insertar

Tags: php, mysql

Me encuentro en la siguiente situación, de una tabla en MYSQL tengo que comparar tres campos si alguno de ellos esta repetido en los resgistros existentes no se debe de proceder a realizar la inserción de los datos.
Realizo la select, pero cuando voy a realizar el where es donde me quedo atascado.

```
$sql= "SELECT a, b, c FROM banco WHERE
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los criterios que debes verificar en el `WHERE`?

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es evitar duplicados, te propongo utilizar claves únicas que, además, te agilizarán las búsquedas:

Opción para evitar duplicados en cada campo:

```
ALTER TABLE banco
  ADD UNIQUE(a),
  ADD UNIQUE(b),
  ADD UNIQUE(c);
```

Opción para evitar ternas duplicadas:

```
ALTER TABLE banco
  ADD UNIQUE(a,b,c);
```

Aporto el dataset por si quieres hacer pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE banco(
  a int,
  b int,
  c int
  );

INSERT INTO banco (a, b, c) VALUES
  (4,5,6);
```

Comment: Debería ser única es la.combinacion de las tres no de esta forma

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @JackNavaRow, hay que diferenciar las cosas, la restricción `UNIQUE (a,b,c)` evitaría que en una misma fila hayan valores repetidos que combinen las columnas  `a,b,c`, pero en tu código no permitirá valores repetidos ni para `a` solo, ni para `b` solo ni para `c` solo, no creo que sea ese el requerimiento.

Comment: Efectivamente, a juzgar por su autorespuesta, parece que es a lo que el OP se refería, yo entendí la otra opción. Modifico la respuesta y lo puntualizo en la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo he realizado como dice Nicolas y me va bien.

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM banco WHERE a = 'substr ($buffer, 0,   1) ' AND  b = 'substr ($buffer, 1,  8)' AND c = 'substr ($buffer, 10,   2)'";
```

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, selecciona la respuesta que te sirvió como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, intenta seleccionar el registro que tienes en tu base de datos. Y en caso de que no exista, entonces puedes hacer el insert. En tu caso quedaría así:

```
INSERT INTO banco (a, b, c)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'valora', 'valorb', 'valorc') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT a, b, c FROM banco WHERE a = 'valora' or b = 'valorb' or c = 'valorc'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Hago el select de los 3 campos y los comparo con los valores que quiero hacer el insert. Si alguno de ellos existe, el where no se cumplirá, por lo tanto, el Insert no se ejecutará.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías formular tu where con el criterio or

```
$sql= "SELECT a, b, c FROM banco WHERE a = '' or b = '' or c = ''"
```

Saludos!